# Como reproducir un audios mp3 y otros en Java

Tags: java, javafx

Buenas, he estado buscando como reproducir un audio mp3 pero aun no me dan resultado. he intentado con la clase Media de JavaFx. ¿Como podría reproducir el audio? sin tener que recurrir a librerías externas.

Comment: yo tambien tengo el mismo error"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: File of unsupported format".... y ya e probado con distintos tipos de archivos de musica....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando `JavaFX` el método más común es mediante la clase **[MediaPlayer](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html)**

Este es un ejemplo, simplemente define la ruta de tu archivo .mp3 y podrás reproducir sin problema el audio:

```
String path = "C:/Mi Musica/AC_DC/Back in Black/06 Back in Black.mp3";
Media media = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
```

Comment: La clase media es abstracta no la puedo instancia.

Comment: Hola Sara, no necesita ser abstracta, que te parece si agregas tu código.

Comment: Ah jaja era el import, no era el adecuado, ya lo pruebo.

Comment: Jeje no te preocupes, saludos!

Comment: Me da el siguiente error: **Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized** Lo ejecute en un nuevo thread pero el error es el mismo.

Comment: Si estas usando JavaFX, inicializa JFXPanel!,  JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();

Comment: ¡Funciona! :) Gracias por tu paciencia.

Answer (score 0):

Existe esta forma:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

import static javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream;
import static javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED;

public class AudioFilePlayer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final AudioFilePlayer player = new AudioFilePlayer ();
        player.play("something.mp3");
        player.play("something.ogg");
    }

    public void play(String filePath) {
        final File file = new File(filePath);

        try (final AudioInputStream in = getAudioInputStream(file)) {

            final AudioFormat outFormat = getOutFormat(in.getFormat());
            final Info info = new Info(SourceDataLine.class, outFormat);

            try (final SourceDataLine line =
                     (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info)) {

                if (line != null) {
                    line.open(outFormat);
                    line.start();
                    stream(getAudioInputStream(outFormat, in), line);
                    line.drain();
                    line.stop();
                }
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException 
               | LineUnavailableException 
               | IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    private AudioFormat getOutFormat(AudioFormat inFormat) {
        final int ch = inFormat.getChannels();

        final float rate = inFormat.getSampleRate();
        return new AudioFormat(PCM_SIGNED, rate, 16, ch, ch * 2, rate, false);
    }

    private void stream(AudioInputStream in, SourceDataLine line) 
        throws IOException {
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        for (int n = 0; n != -1; n = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) {
            line.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
    }
}
```

y [aqui](https://odoepner.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/play-mp3-or-ogg-using-javax-sound-sampled-mp3spi-vorbisspi/) esta la referencia:

Comment: Me tira el siguiente error: "javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input file" y la dirrecion es correcta.

Comment: prueba con otro tipo de archivo, pusiste un .mp3?? eso generalmente pasa con wav. En esta url hay otra forma que intenta resolver esas excepciones: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info